# Do conductors have temperature coefficient of resistance of order $0.1$ [1/K] at $40 - 160$ Kelvin?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance

Typical metals have temperature coefficient of resistance with order of magnitude $\sim 0.001$, at $20$ degrees Celsius.

What kind of materials have TCR of order of magnitude $0.1$ at $40 - 160$ Kelvin?

I want to know what kind of material show behavior like the measurement results in the below picture.
I conjecture that it is not insulator, semi-conductor, and super conductor. So I conjectured that it must be a conductor, but all conductors seem to have temperature coefficient $<0.006$, (at $293$K).

I know that the TCR itself depends on temperature, so it might be that the TCR of metals are about $0.1$ at low temperatures,  but I could not find any reference of temperature coefficient of metals in the $20-160$ K regime.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Resistance - Temperature]

Comment: Low temperature resistivities in metals may well decrease rapidly at low temperatures (particularly for ones that go superconducting). You might want to find a handbook of properties of materials at low temperature (NBS, now NIST, had a series of them).

Comment: See, for example, https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrd155.pdf